# Unable to get third level of Hierarchical Data Template to populate in Silverlight TreeView Control

Tags: c#, silverlight, treeview, silverlight-5.0, hierarchicaldatatemplate

Hello and thanks in advance for any help you can give. I have been trying to bind data to a treeView through use of a Hierarchical data template in Silverlight 5. I am trying to achieve a hierarchy with three levels. However, my template is only able to produce two. No matter what I try nothing appears in the third level, even though there are three Hierarchical data templates each using the predecessor as an item template. My xaml looks as follows:

```
<sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ModTemplate" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ServerChildren}" >
    <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding Path=ServerName}" />
</sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ChildTemplate2" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ServerChildren}"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ModTemplate}">
    <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding Path=ServerName}" />
</sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="GroupNameTemplate" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ServerChildren}" 
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildTemplate2}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=GroupName}" FontWeight="Bold" />
</sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

The data context of the TreeView is set in the code behind to an observable collection of the ServerOCollection class, which in turn has an ObservableCollection of the ServerObject class, which in turn has an ObserverableCollection of the ModuleObject class. I am able to get the first two levels of the TreeView to populate accordingly but can get nothing to show up in the third! Please help!

Edit: I was able to get the desired results by changing the templates to the following:

```
<sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ModTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding ApplicationModules}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <ContentPresenter Margin="0 0 4 0" Content="{Binding Icon}" />
                <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding Path=ModuleName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ChildTemplate2" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ApplicationModules}"
                                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ModTemplate}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding Path=ServerName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="GroupNameTemplate" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ServerChildren}" 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildTemplate2}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ContentPresenter Margin="0 0 4 0" Content="{Binding GroupIcon}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=GroupName}" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </StackPanel>
        </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: You are Binding the text to `ServerName` in both the second and third levels... is this correct?

Comment: I had changed the original binding of the third level to ServerName in an effort to get anything to display in the third level, since that attribute successfully displayed in the the second. That may have been incorrect thinking. However when I changed the xaml to the the xaml shown in the above edit I was able to get the desired results. Thank you for looking into my question though.